# IOS/Storyboard: Adapt view to different size devices

Tags: ios, storyboard, adaptive-layout

I have an app originally prototyped with an iphone 4.  However, when I display it on an iphone 5 or above, it leaves a black border on the top and bottom as shown. How can I get it to fill up screen?  Using the size inspector I have set the screen height of the VC and view to arbitrarily high values such as 2000 but that has no effect.  I also tried changing the top bar from inferred to none with no effect.

Thanks for any suggestions.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your app, you need to define launch/splash screens for all supported devices. You can do this either using launch screen storyboard (preferred) or launch static images. Follow this -

https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/launch-screen/

When you create a new Xcode project, Xcode automatically puts launch screen storyboard for you but your project seems to be old so you need to put yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Use auto layout with size classes.
Here is a good tutorial
https://www.raywenderlich.com/113768/adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-getting-started

Basically vertical spacing is the problem here.
Just learning the basic autolayout stuff will solve this problem

Comment: You are right that project needs to be updated with autolayout.  Thanks for link to the tutorial.